# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[QBDDXMLElement attributeFloatValueForName:withDefaultValue:]:

Tags: iphone, quickblox

```
- (void)completedWithResult:(Result *)result{
   // QuickBlox session creation  result
    if([result isKindOfClass:[QBAAuthSessionCreationResult class]]){

        // Success result
        if(result.success){

            // Set QuickBlox Chat delegate
            //
            [QBChat instance].delegate = self;

            QBUUser *user = [QBUUser user];
            user.ID = ((QBAAuthSessionCreationResult *)result).session.userID;
            user.password  = @"password";


            // Login to QuickBlox Chat

            [[QBChat instance] loginWithUser:user];
        }
        else
        {

            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[[result errors] description] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        }
    }
}
```

**-[QBDDXMLElement attributeFloatValueForName:withDefaultValue:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x96c4fe0
2013-12-10 16:06:46.716 QUickBloxTestApp[5990:3907]**  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[QBDDXMLElement attributeFloatValueForName:withDefaultValue:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x96c4fe0'*

App crashes while it invoke [[QBChat instance] loginWithUser:user];

Comment: Assuming you're not calling a method named `attributeFloatValueForName:withDefaultValue:` directly, I'd try turning on zombies in your build scheme and seeing if it provides any better information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this guide http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS-how-to-connect-Quickblox-framework

Looks like you forgot to add some frameworks like **libxml**, **libresolv**, **libz** or so